# calculate size of structure that has structure with in it

Tags: c++, c, structure

I have a structure say:

```
struct sub_struct
{
 short  int  alpha; //2 bytes
 short  int  beta;
 short  int gamma;

}

struct big_struct
{
 char movie;
 char songs;
 short int release;

 sub_struct temp_struct[ 4 ];

}
```

Somewhere in code I have to check sizeof struct so for that I define in header something like:

```
const int LEN_BIG_STRUCT = sizeof( big_struct );
```

Now my question is Will `LEN_BIG_STRUCT` also include the size of sub_struct or do I need to define size of sub struct as well? if yes then how would I do?

Comment: The best way to find out is to try it out, no?

Comment: It's like with those russian dolls: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll ;-)

Comment: A useful reference and explanation of how this works: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine `big_struct` as a basket, which you have put a smaller basket, `sub_struct`, inside of.

If you now were to put the big basket, containing the small basket, on a scale; you'd be kinda surprised if the weight didn't include that of the small basket, wouldn't you?

It's a good thing `sizeof` does the expected..

---

#### In other words...

Yes, `sizeof` yields the total number of bytes that takes part in the object representation of its operand; including any potential padding.

---

Here's what the C++ Standard says about `sizeof`:

> When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in array.

<sub>**Note**: The operator works the same way in C.</sub>

---

Comment: Thank s Filip it means I dont need to explicitily define sizeof(sub_struct) right ?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(x)` returns the total amount of bytes by the variable or type `x`.

---

In your case:

- `small_struct`: 6 bytes total (2 from each `short int`).
- `big_struct`: 2 `char` and 1 `short`, as well as an array of
  `small_struct` which totals to 24 bytes (4 elements * 6 bytes).

So `sizeof(big_struct)` returns `28` as the total number of bytes.

To answer your question, you don't need to define the size of `small_struct` because `sizeof()` adds all bytes encompassed in the struct like Filip Roséen stated in his answer.

---

**Note:** *as the comments stated below, `28` bytes for `big_struct` is not universal on all systems. This is due to data padding in C. You can read a bit about it below:*

- http://learn.hackerearth.com/tutorial/dynamic-programming/31/structure-padding-and-data-packing/
- http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-structure-padding/

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about sizes of types. `char` is always 1 byte, but `short int` is not necessarily 2 bytes, and there could be padding between members of any struct or after the last member. `sizeof` accounts for all this, so these assumptions aren't even necessary.

Comment: How do you know the sizes of those types on the OP implementation ?

Comment: I was trying to give the OP a concrete example so he/she can get a grasp of what `sizeof` is doing. I understand that different  architectures/compilers or various types in a struct could constitute arbitrary padding somewhere. So for simplicity's sake I assumed no padding (in the order the types are in). I will edit the answer with a note at the bottom.